# Cant fix syntax error and expected a expression error in VS 2022

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2022

I´m at my second week learning C++ and now i stumbled upon a problem I cant seem to fix.
I know how to make structs and use them but I get error codes E0029 and C2059 when I try to debug and run my code.

[Print Screen of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikH8h.png)

```
#include <iostream>

struct Car
{
    std::string make;
    std::string model;
    int year;
    double cost;
};

int main()
{
    Car myCar;
    
    myCar;
    { .make = "Tesla", .model : "Model Y", .year = 2020, .cost : 60000; };

    return 0;


}
```

I know how to do this in other ways, it's only when I do it like this I get these error codes.

Comment: `myCar;` is a separate statement that does nothing useful. Then you have the statement-block containing initializers which are the actual syntax errors. I assume you really wanted to do `Car myCar { ... };`? And no semicolon in the initializer list, it's terminated by the closing curly brace.

Comment: You probably meant to write `Car myCar{ .make = "Tesla", .model : "Model Y", .year = 2020, .cost : 60000; };`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I see now that I had some misstyping. This is my original code. 

int main()
{
    Car myCar { .make : "Tesla", .model : "Model Y", .year : 2020, .cost : 60000 };

    return 0;

}

Comment: Then please [edit] your question to show your *actual* code, a proper [mre]. Also please copy-paste (as text) the full build-log from the `Output` tab into your question.

Comment: you also need #include <string>

Comment: And please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot initialize a struct in this way. You can do the initialization with initializer_list, but remember that the fields of the structure are initialized in the order they are declared, for example:

```
myCar = { "Tesla", "Model Y", 2020, 60000 };
```

or use this:

```
myCar = { .make = "Tesla", .model = "Model Y", .year = 2020, .cost = 60000 };
```

Answer (score -1):

use this syntax:

```
  Car myCar;
  myCar = { .make = "Tesla", .model : "Model Y", .year = 2020, .cost : 60000; };
```